# Difference in timestamp (2nd row and 1st row) and (3rd row and 2nd row) on the same column with comma separated identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as below:

```
Eventid                      action  callstatus datetime                  
----------------------       ------  ---------- --------                  
948687,948689,948690,948691, GR      NEW       14-DEC-17 05.10.07.000000000 AM
948690                       UR      WIP       14-DEC-17 05.10.22.000000000 AM      
948690                       UR      DONE      14-DEC-17 05.10.23.000000000 AM
```

Need to get the time difference between Row2 and Row1 of datetime column and difference between Row3 and Row2 of datetime column.

I need to do this for multiple eventid's as input.

Please assist.

Comment: I can imagine a few ways of doing this, but first I want to ask why you are storing CSV data in the `Eventid` column?  To make matters worse, sometimes you store CSV and sometimes you don't.  Well, just _don't_ store CSV at all, and it would make this question much easier.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? They manage date/time in different ways.

Comment: Jarlh - I am using Oracle.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen - this table is a audit table just for the reference purpose. Dev team has not created a seperate column to store this info.

Comment: @Siva Then why did you tag sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle solution. You have to turn `eventid` into separate rows. There are many ways, here I used "xmltable" method. And then use `lag` to calculate difference.

```
with t(eventid, action, callstatus, datetime) as (
    select '948687,948689,948690,948691,', 'GR', 'NEW', 
                                   timestamp '2017-12-14 05:10:07' from dual union all
    select '948690', 'UR', 'WIP',  timestamp '2017-12-14 05:10:22' from dual union all
    select '948690', 'UR', 'DONE', timestamp '2017-12-14 05:10:23' from dual ),
-- end of simulated data, query starts here:
cte as (
    select t.*, '"'||replace(t.eventid, ',', '","')||'"' evid from t)
select trim(column_value) eid, eventid, action, callstatus, datetime,
       datetime - lag(datetime) over (partition by trim(column_value) order by datetime) diff
  from cte, xmltable(evid)
  order by 1, datetime
```

Output:

```
EID     EVENTID                      ACTION CALLSTATUS DATETIME          DIFF
------- ---------------------------- ------ ---------- ----------------- -------------------
948687  948687,948689,948690,948691, GR     NEW        17/12/14 05:10:07
948689  948687,948689,948690,948691, GR     NEW        17/12/14 05:10:07
948690  948687,948689,948690,948691, GR     NEW        17/12/14 05:10:07
948690  948690                       UR     WIP        17/12/14 05:10:22 +000000000 00:00:15
948690  948690                       UR     DONE       17/12/14 05:10:23 +000000000 00:00:01
948691  948687,948689,948690,948691, GR     NEW        17/12/14 05:10:07
```

Comment: Many thanks @Ponder Stibbons. If I want to do for multiple event id's (like 100's and 200's of event id's), how i can manipulate the quer? basically i have multiple rows of event id's.

Comment: As you can see in the example this query works for any number of events.

Answer (score 0):

This is Oracle DB. I am using SQL like this. But want to tweak a little bit for multiple event id's and a proper output of time difference

Any suggestions?

select eventid, datetime - lead(datetime) over (order by datetime) from AWS2.audit_comm_data where eventid like '%948643%' or eventid like '%948690%';